# I cannot see installed packages in venv folder

Tags: python, pycharm, virtualenv

Using Pycharm Community Edition and have virtualenv activated. My venv directory structure is this:

```
venv/
├── bin
│   ├── activate
│   ├── activate.csh
│   ├── activate.fish
│   ├── python
│   └── python3
├── include
├── lib
│   └── python3.7
│       └── site-packages
└── pyvenv.cfg
```

Question is: where are my 3rd party libraries which I'm sure I'm using bs4 and such, which is not reflected in the directory structure?
Also, I can tell that pip is installed into my project environment from Pycharm GUI, still there is no such thing in venv directory.

Can I get an explanation for how my virtual environment look up for these dependency please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The libs are supposed to be in the `venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/`
They are themselves folders containing binaries and `so` files. Perhaps you did inadvertently installed them in you `user` directory?

If you want to know your local installed packages, run the following command in you `virtualenv`:

```py
pip freeze --local
```

Also, `pip list --local` gives a prettier output, but `pip freeze --local > requirements.txt` is very useful to cat your current `pip` setup into a requirement file.